# Implementing sjf scheduling to netbeans user-interface java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

So I have a sjf scheduling algorithm that i found online and i wanted to implement it on gui
but im running into problems because i dont know how to merge the code and gui properly

```
import java.util.*;

class sjf {

static int z = 100000000;
static int sh = 100000;

static class util {

    // Process ID
    int id;
    // Arrival time
    int at;
    // Burst time
    int bt;
    // Completion time
    int ct;
    // Turnaround time
    int tat;
    // Waiting time
    int wt;
}

// Array to store all the process information
// by implementing the above struct util
static util[] ar = new util[sh + 1];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < sh + 1; i++) {
        ar[i] = new util();
    }
}

static class util1 {

    // Process id
    int p_id;
    // burst time
    int bt1;
};

static util1 range = new util1();

// Segment tree array to
// process the queries in nlogn
static util1[] tr = new util1[4 * sh + 5];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * sh + 5; i++) {
        tr[i] = new util1();
    }
}

// To keep an account of where
// a particular process_id is
// in the segment tree base array
static int[] mp = new int[sh + 1];

// Comparator function to sort the
// struct array according to arrival time

// Function to update the burst time and process id
// in the segment tree
static void update(int node, int st, int end,
                    int ind, int id1, int b_t)
{
    if (st == end) {
        tr[node].p_id = id1;
        tr[node].bt1 = b_t;
        return;
    }
    int mid = (st + end) / 2;
    if (ind <= mid)
        update(2 * node, st, mid, ind, id1, b_t);
    else
        update(2 * node + 1, mid + 1, end, ind, id1, b_t);
    if (tr[2 * node].bt1 < tr[2 * node + 1].bt1) {
        tr[node].bt1 = tr[2 * node].bt1;
        tr[node].p_id = tr[2 * node].p_id;
    } else {
        tr[node].bt1 = tr[2 * node + 1].bt1;
        tr[node].p_id = tr[2 * node + 1].p_id;
    }
}

// Function to return the range minimum of the burst time
// of all the arrived processes using segment tree
static util1 query(int node, int st, int end,
                    int lt, int rt)
{
    if (end < lt || st > rt)
        return range;
    if (st >= lt && end <= rt)
        return tr[node];
    int mid = (st + end) / 2;
    util1 lm = query(2 * node, st, mid, lt, rt);
    util1 rm = query(2 * node + 1, mid + 1, end, lt, rt);
    if (lm.bt1 < rm.bt1)
        return lm;
    return rm;
}

// Function to perform non_preemptive
// shortest job first and return the
// completion time, turn around time and
// waiting time for the given processes
static void non_premptive_sjf(int n) {

    // To store the number of processes
    // that have been completed
    int counter = n;

    // To keep an account of the number
    // of processes that have been arrived
    int upper_range = 0;

    // Current running time
    int tm = Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ar[upper_range + 1].at);

    // To find the list of processes whose arrival time
    // is less than or equal to the current time
    while (counter != 0) {
        for (; upper_range <= n;) {
            upper_range++;
            if (ar[upper_range].at > tm || upper_range > n) {
                upper_range--;
                break;
            }

            update(1, 1, n, upper_range, ar[upper_range].id,
                    ar[upper_range].bt);
        }

        // To find the minimum of all the running times
        // from the set of processes whose arrival time is
        // less than or equal to the current time
        util1 res = query(1, 1, n, 1, upper_range);

        // Checking if the process has already been executed
        if (res.bt1 != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            counter--;
            int index = mp[res.p_id];
            tm += (res.bt1);

            // Calculating and updating the array with
            // the current time, turn around time and waiting time
            ar[index].ct = tm;
            ar[index].tat = ar[index].ct - ar[index].at;
            ar[index].wt = ar[index].tat - ar[index].bt;

            // Update the process burst time with
            // infinity when the process is executed
            update(1, 1, n, index, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        } else {
            tm = ar[upper_range + 1].at;
        }
    }
}

// Function to call the functions and perform
// shortest job first operation
static void execute(int n) {

    // Sort the array based on the arrival times
    Arrays.sort(ar, 1, n, new Comparator<util>() {
        public int compare(util a, util b) {
            if (a.at == b.at)
                return a.id - b.id;
            return a.at - b.at;
        }
    });
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        mp[ar[i].id] = i;

    // Calling the function to perform
    // non-premptive-sjf
    non_premptive_sjf(n);
}

// Function to print the required values after
// performing shortest job first
static void print(int n) {

    System.out.println("ProcessId Arrival Time Burst Time" +
            " Completion Time Turn Around Time Waiting Time");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",
             ar[i].id, ar[i].at, ar[i].bt, ar[i].ct, ar[i].tat,
                ar[i].wt);
    }
}

// Driver Code
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Number of processes
    int n = 5;

    // Initializing the process id
    // and burst time
    range.p_id = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    range.bt1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4 * sh + 1; i++)
    {
        tr[i].p_id = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        tr[i].bt1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    // Arrival time, Burst time and ID
    // of the processes on which SJF needs
    // to be performed
    ar[1].at = 0;
    ar[1].bt = 9;
    ar[1].id = 1;

    ar[2].at = 1;
    ar[2].bt = 7;
    ar[2].id = 2;

    ar[3].at = 3;
    ar[3].bt = 5;
    ar[3].id = 3;

    ar[4].at = 6;
    ar[4].bt = 11;
    ar[4].id = 4;

    ar[5].at = 8;
    ar[5].bt = 4;
    ar[5].id = 5;

    execute(n);

    // Print the calculated time
    print(n);
}
}
```

[image: Gui]

This is the gui im trying to create where every colomn jtextfield variable is named respectivly
p1,p2...
at1,at2...
bt1,bt2...
time1,time2...
tat1,tat2...
wt1,wt2...

So what i've done so fare is i copied the code above into gui

the code below i deleted it from the original code

```
ar[1].at = 0;
ar[1].bt = 9;
ar[1].id = 1;

ar[2].at = 1;
ar[2].bt = 7;
ar[2].id = 2;

ar[3].at = 3;
ar[3].bt = 5;
ar[3].id = 3;

ar[4].at = 6;
ar[4].bt = 11;
ar[4].id = 4;

ar[5].at = 8;
ar[5].bt = 4;
ar[5].id = 5;

execute(n);
```

I've done this to every jtextfield where I've assigned the proper array values for every jtextfield

```
private void p1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    String a = p1.getText();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(a);
    ar[1].id = number;
    
}
```

Did this with the run button

```
private void RunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    
    
    ct1.setText(String.valueOf(ar[1].ct));
    ct2.setText(String.valueOf(ar[2].ct));
    ct3.setText(String.valueOf(ar[3].ct));
    ct4.setText(String.valueOf(ar[4].ct));
    ct5.setText(String.valueOf(ar[5].ct));
    
    tat1.setText(String.valueOf(ar[1].tat));
    tat2.setText(String.valueOf(ar[2].tat));
    tat3.setText(String.valueOf(ar[3].tat));
    tat4.setText(String.valueOf(ar[4].tat));
    tat5.setText(String.valueOf(ar[5].tat));
    
    wt1.setText(String.valueOf(ar[1].wt));
    wt2.setText(String.valueOf(ar[2].wt));
    wt3.setText(String.valueOf(ar[3].wt));
    wt4.setText(String.valueOf(ar[4].wt));
    wt5.setText(String.valueOf(ar[5].wt));
    
    
}
```

And tried to remove the original code main method and place the contents to the gui methods but still the output of the comp time, turn around time, waiting time comes 0

Comment: What you should do is: when you click on Run, read all the values from the text fields, validate them, store them and then call the SJF scheduling function.